# Change size of views inside ContainerView programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, uicontainerview

I have a container view which is equally divided between two UIViews like this:

[image]

The portion in black is my **UIView 1**, which I am currently not using. My **UIView 2** contains a UISegmented Bar and a UITableView.

The hierarchy of my views look something like this:

[image]

Now, my requirement is I want to resize my view2 to cover entire container view dynamically and view1 to go away based on some condition. Currently I am not worried about that condition, I just tried to resize my view2 using the following code inside `- (void)viewDidLoad`

```
CGRect newFrame = self.view2.frame;
newFrame.size.width = 200;
newFrame.size.height = 200;
newFrame.origin.x=0;
newFrame.origin.y=0;
[self.view2 setFrame:newFrame];
```

Here `view2` is the outlet to my view2 in interface builder.

But, nothing is changing from the above code. I tried to find any other way but had no help. So please help me find out my mistake in my current technique or tell me how some other technique to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: view != nil ? You have constraints?

Comment: No, I have no constraints.

Comment: try self.view2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to change frame seems fine, just remove the view from superview, set the frame and add to superview again programmatically.

```
[self.view2 removeFromSuperview];
// set the frame
CGRect newFrame = self.view2.frame;
newFrame.size.width = 200;
newFrame.size.height = 200;
newFrame.origin.x=0;
newFrame.origin.y=0;
[self.view2 setFrame:newFrame];

//add self.view2 again wherever it was
[myView addSubView:self.view2];
```

Comment: sorry but can you guide me how to do it programmatically?

Comment: @ Fawad Masud hey I am facing a little problem with the above solution, once I resize my view2 my unsegmented bar is not responding to touch. I did little bit of debugging by changing color of view2 to red and found that the view2 is actually not resizing. Although the unsegmented bar and table view did change their origin, but view2 is getting disappeared. Can you help me find the problem?

Comment: @Exception try setting userInteractionEnabled property of view2 to YES. Also make sure you are adding view2 on the same view it was initially added to. Also you may need to set the frames of subviews of view2.

Comment: I removed all subviews of view2 and tried just to resize view2 but it is not getting resized. The problem I think is with view2 only.

Comment: `if (1)
    {
        
        CGRect newFrame = self.view2.frame;
        UIView *superView=self.view2.superview;
        [self.view2 removeFromSuperview];
        [self.view1 removeFromSuperview];                
        newFrame.size.width =703;
        newFrame.size.height =632;
        newFrame.origin.x=0;
        newFrame.origin.y=0;
        [self.view2 setFrame:newFrame];       
        [superView addSubview:self.view2];
        
    }`

Comment: The problem is with UIView *superView=self.view2.superview;  You are creating a new instance of UIView  named as superview. add view2 back to the original superview.

Comment: I also tried it by creating an outlet of the main view of the view controller and doing the same to it but still no success.